# Scaling values on the selected axis

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, syncfusion

I have a chart using Syncfusion LineSeries.

I would like to scale the data on the X axis. Only the same values in the graph (the data on the axis label should be the same as it is now)

In short, the visible graph should be horizontally downloaded (e.g. scaled down 10 times)

Can it be done?

Just dividing the value by 10 does not change anything when the chart continues to fill the chart completely.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UL8mQ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We would like to suggest the following chart axis features.

Maximum property used for setting the maximum value for the axis range

Minimum property is used for setting the minimum value for the axis range.

EnableAutoIntervalOnZooming property is used to maintain the interval even it is in zooming state only if we set the interval to the axis. Default value of this property is true. While zooming based on the auto range padding the interval will be calculated.

For more details, please refer below UG,

https://help.syncfusion.com/wpf/charts/axis

Note: I am working in Syncfusion.